# Applescript Access Variables Through Run Script

Tags: applescript

Let's say I have a script:

```
set hi to 7
run script "display dialog hi"
```

When I run it, it says that `hi` is undefined.

Is there a way to make `hi` accessible from the `run script` command? If not, what else can I do? The real application for this is to change a variable name. What I do now is:

```
    repeat (random number from 0 to 5) times
    set rand2 to (random number from 0 to 7) + 97
    set rand to (random number from 0 to 7) + 97
    set switch to rand2
    run script ("set " & (ASCII character rand) & "1 to " & (ASCII character rand2) & "1")
    run script ("set " & (ASCII character rand2) & "1 to " & (ASCII character switch) & "1")
    run script ("set " & (ASCII character rand) & "2 to " & (ASCII character rand2) & "2")
    run script ("set " & (ASCII character rand2) & "2 to " & (ASCII character switch) & "2")
end repeat
```

But that doesn't work. Is these I workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the variables to persist in the same scope, you have to run your whole variable switcharoos in the same run script command.

This demonstrates how to add variable to the text of the run script. It would return a list of results from the variables. However, this/your script doesn't work because you're assigning rand+1 to rand2+1, before the variable rand2+1 has been assigned. I do not know what it is you're trying to accomplish, so can't fix more of your script.
But, this answers your specific original question, syntax for adding variables into the text of a run script string.

```
repeat (random number from 0 to 5) times
    set rand2 to (ASCII character ((random number from 0 to 7) + 97))
    set rand to (ASCII character ((random number from 0 to 7) + 97))
    set switch to rand2

    set scriptText to ("set " & rand & "1 to " & rand2 & "1" & return & ¬
        "set " & rand2 & "1 to " & switch & "1" & return & ¬
        "set " & rand & "2 to " & rand2 & "2" & return & ¬
        "set " & rand2 & "2 to " & switch & "2" & return & ¬
        "return {" & rand & "1, " & rand2 & "1, " & rand & "2, " & rand2 & "2}")
    set theResult to run script scriptText
end repeat
```

Comment: But that doesn't allow me to access variables outside `run script`, which is what I need (I'm sorry if that wasn't clear). So basically is there a way to `set` a variable via `run script` that exists outside of `run script`?

Comment: Basically I just want an answer to my first script

Comment: If you want an actual answer to your main problem, you need to provide more details/context for your script to get help with what you're trying to accomplish. As I said below, your script you provided makes no sense, since you're setting one variable to another variable before it is defined. And, you should ask it in its own topic.

Comment: I think you're not being clear about setting what variable in front of or behind a "run script". You can set a variable via run script:  set x to run script "return 2"

Comment: Basically I'm picking two random variables that are predefined and switching them around.

Comment: Excellent... but I still don't understand the goal, what you're trying to accomplish, so sorry can't help more. Do you understand what I'm saying that your script is broken?  let's say rand ends up being "c", and rand2 is "g".  You are setting c1 to g1 before you ever declare and assign a value to g1, so your script is broken as it is.

Comment: I already assign a-i and then 1 and 2 before this script is run